# Suppress hyperlinks to current page

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

Is it possible to suppress hyperlinks pointing to the same page as the hyperlink?

I currently use the hyperref and cleveref packages for the hyperlinks, but I don't find any option to disable hyperlinks pointing to the current page (without using the \ref* option). Is this possible with these, or any other, packages, or does anyone have any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s one solution using the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{
  \ifnumequal{\thepage}{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}
    {\ref*{#1}}{\ref{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{An empty figure}
  \label{fig:empty}
\end{figure}

This is a reference on the same page.~[\myref{fig:empty}]

  \pagebreak

This is a reference on a different page.~[\myref{fig:empty}]

\end{document}
```

The command `\myref` uses `\ifnumequal` from `etoolbox` to check if the current page number and the referenced page number are the same (using `refcount` to get these page numbers as numbers rather than strings).

If the two are the same, then it uses the unlinked form `\ref*`; otherwise it uses `\ref`. This means that the reference on the first page isn’t clickable, but the second page is.

You’d need to set up corresponding macros for any other reference commands you use, and I’d suggest using different names. (`\mypageref`, `\myhref`, and so on). Trying to overwrite macro names from `hyperref` makes it an unhappy package.

I’m sure you could similarly adapt this solution to work with `cleverref`.